# Calling external script from Flink

Tags: apache-flink

This might seem like a very complex problem to some of you. I want to use Apache Flink to apply some algorithms on data from a SocketStream. However, these algorithms are external executables that I am running using Scala's `sys.process` package. Here is what I want Flink to do:

1. Get individual lines from SocketStream:

   `val text = env.socketTextStream(hostName, port) 
    val lines = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\n") filter { _.nonEmpty } }`
2. Call my executable algorithm with these lines as command line parameters. Somewhat like this:

   `var op = "./Somefile.py "+lines!`
3. Print the output I get from the executable.

   `op.print()`

Obviously this is not the correct way to do what I am trying to do as `op` unlike `lines` is not a data sink and thus nothing is getting printed. Is there some way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put all arguments into a single String value, you can call the external executable from a `MapFunction`.

This would look like:

```
val args: DataStream[String] = env.socketTextStream(hostName, port) 
// assume each text line has all elements
val out: DataStream[String] = args.map(new ExternalCaller())
// print result
out.print()
```

with

```
class ExternalCaller extends MapFunction[String, String] {

  override def map(args: String): String = {
    // call external executable with args here and return output
  }
}
```

Comment: I kind of figured that it could be done with `map`, but this solved my problem. Thanks.